# Remove ResponseEntity in swagger-codegen-maven-plugin api class

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I generated api classes with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin, and methods return ResponseEntity

```
@ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "getBlockingByMdmdId", notes = "", response = BlockingDto.class, tags={ "blocklist", })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = BlockingDto.class) })
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/blocklist/{id}",
    produces = "*/*", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<BlockingDto> getBlockingByMdmdId(@ApiParam(value = "", required=true) @PathVariable("mdmId") String mdmId);
```

How can I change return type from `ResponseEntity<BlockingDto>` to `BlockingDto` with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin?

Comment: I guess it also happened to you after you upgraded to 3.0.33?

Answer (score 0):

you can use mustache template to customize your generated api interfaces.

add the following files to your project **api.mustache** and **bodyParams.mustache**
in the following path ***src\main\resources\openapi-templates***

**api.mustache**

```
/**
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech) ({{{generatorVersion}}}).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 */
package {{package}};

{{#imports}}import {{import}};
{{/imports}}
{{#swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameters;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
{{/swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
{{#swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
{{/swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
{{#jdk8-no-delegate}}
{{#virtualService}}
import io.virtualan.annotation.ApiVirtual;
import io.virtualan.annotation.VirtualService;
{{/virtualService}}
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
{{/jdk8-no-delegate}}
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
{{#useBeanValidation}}
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
{{/useBeanValidation}}
{{#useSpringController}}
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
{{/useSpringController}}
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
{{#jdk8-no-delegate}}
{{^reactive}}
import org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest;
{{/reactive}}
{{/jdk8-no-delegate}}
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
{{#reactive}}
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.Part;
{{/reactive}}

{{#useBeanValidation}}
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
{{/useBeanValidation}}
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
{{#jdk8-no-delegate}}
import java.util.Optional;
{{/jdk8-no-delegate}}
{{^jdk8-no-delegate}}
{{#useOptional}}
import java.util.Optional;
{{/useOptional}}
{{/jdk8-no-delegate}}
{{#async}}
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
{{/async}}
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

{{>generatedAnnotation}}
{{#useBeanValidation}}
@Validated
{{/useBeanValidation}}
{{#useSpringController}}
@Controller
{{/useSpringController}}
{{#swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
@Tag(name = "{{{baseName}}}", description = {{#tagDescription}}"{{{.}}}"{{/tagDescription}}{{^tagDescription}}"the {{{baseName}}} API"{{/tagDescription}})
{{/swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
{{#swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
@Api(value = "{{{baseName}}}", description = {{#tagDescription}}"{{{.}}}"{{/tagDescription}}{{^tagDescription}}"the {{{baseName}}} API"{{/tagDescription}})
{{/swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
{{#operations}}
{{#virtualService}}
@VirtualService
{{/virtualService}}
public interface {{classname}} {
{{#jdk8-default-interface}}
    {{^isDelegate}}
        {{^reactive}}

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
        {{/reactive}}
    {{/isDelegate}}
    {{#isDelegate}}

    default {{classname}}Delegate getDelegate() {
        return new {{classname}}Delegate() {};
    }
    {{/isDelegate}}
{{/jdk8-default-interface}}
{{#operation}}

    /**
     * {{httpMethod}} {{{path}}}{{#summary}} : {{.}}{{/summary}}
    {{#notes}}
     * {{.}}
    {{/notes}}
     *
    {{#allParams}}
     * @param {{paramName}} {{description}}{{#required}} (required){{/required}}{{^required}} (optional{{#defaultValue}}, default to {{.}}{{/defaultValue}}){{/required}}
    {{/allParams}}
     * @return {{#responses}}{{message}} (status code {{code}}){{^-last}}
     *         or {{/-last}}{{/responses}}
    {{#isDeprecated}}
     * @deprecated
    {{/isDeprecated}}
    {{#externalDocs}}
     * {{description}}
     * @see <a href="{{url}}">{{summary}} Documentation</a>
    {{/externalDocs}}
     */
    {{#virtualService}}
    @ApiVirtual
    {{/virtualService}}
    {{#swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
    @Operation(
        operationId = "{{{operationId}}}",
        {{#summary}}
        summary = "{{{.}}}",
        {{/summary}}
        {{#description}}
        description= "{{{.}}}",
        {{/description}}
        {{#vendorExtensions.x-tags.size}}
        tags = { {{#vendorExtensions.x-tags}}"{{tag}}"{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/vendorExtensions.x-tags}} },
        {{/vendorExtensions.x-tags.size}}
        responses = {
            {{#responses}}
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "{{{code}}}", description = "{{{message}}}"{{#baseType}}, content = {
                {{#produces}}
                @Content(mediaType = "{{{mediaType}}}", schema = @Schema(implementation = {{{baseType}}}.class)){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
                {{/produces}}
            }{{/baseType}}){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
            {{/responses}}
        }{{#hasAuthMethods}},
        security = {
            {{#authMethods}}
            @SecurityRequirement(name = "{{name}}"{{#isOAuth}}, scopes={ {{#scopes}}"{{scope}}"{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/scopes}} }{{/isOAuth}}){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
            {{/authMethods}}
        }{{/hasAuthMethods}}
    )
    {{/swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
    {{#swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
    @ApiOperation(
        {{#vendorExtensions.x-tags.size}}
        tags = { {{#vendorExtensions.x-tags}}"{{tag}}"{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/vendorExtensions.x-tags}} },
        {{/vendorExtensions.x-tags.size}}
        value = "{{{summary}}}",
        nickname = "{{{operationId}}}",
        notes = "{{{notes}}}"{{#returnBaseType}},
        response = {{{.}}}.class{{/returnBaseType}}{{#returnContainer}},
        responseContainer = "{{{.}}}"{{/returnContainer}}{{#hasAuthMethods}},
        authorizations = {
        {{#authMethods}}
        {{#isOAuth}}
            @Authorization(value = "{{name}}", scopes = {
            {{#scopes}}
                @AuthorizationScope(scope = "{{scope}}", description = "{{description}}"){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
            {{/scopes}}
            }){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
        {{/isOAuth}}
        {{^isOAuth}}
            @Authorization(value = "{{name}}"){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
        {{/isOAuth}}
        {{/authMethods}} }{{/hasAuthMethods}}
    )
    @ApiResponses({
        {{#responses}}
        @ApiResponse(code = {{{code}}}, message = "{{{message}}}"{{#baseType}}, response = {{{.}}}.class{{/baseType}}{{#containerType}}, responseContainer = "{{{.}}}"{{/containerType}}){{^-last}},{{/-last}}
        {{/responses}}
    })
    {{/swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
    {{#implicitHeadersParams.0}}
    {{#swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
    @Parameters({
        {{#implicitHeadersParams}}
        {{>paramDoc}}{{^-last}},{{/-last}}
        {{/implicitHeadersParams}}
    {{/swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}
    {{#swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        {{#implicitHeadersParams}}
        {{>implicitHeader}}{{^-last}},{{/-last}}
        {{/implicitHeadersParams}}
    {{/swagger1AnnotationLibrary}}
    })
    {{/implicitHeadersParams.0}}
    @{{#lambda.titlecase}}{{#lambda.lowercase}}{{httpMethod}}{{/lambda.lowercase}}{{/lambda.titlecase}}Mapping(
        value = "{{{path}}}"{{#singleContentTypes}}{{#hasProduces}},
        produces = "{{{vendorExtensions.x-accepts}}}"{{/hasProduces}}{{#hasConsumes}},
        consumes = "{{{vendorExtensions.x-contentType}}}"{{/hasConsumes}}{{/singleContentTypes}}{{^singleContentTypes}}{{#hasProduces}},
        produces = { {{#produces}}"{{{mediaType}}}"{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}{{/produces}} }{{/hasProduces}}{{#hasConsumes}},
        consumes = { {{#consumes}}"{{{mediaType}}}"{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}{{/consumes}} }{{/hasConsumes}}{{/singleContentTypes}}
    )
    {{#jdk8-default-interface}}default {{/jdk8-default-interface}}{{#responseWrapper}}{{.}}<{{/responseWrapper}}{{>returnTypes}}{{#responseWrapper}}>{{/responseWrapper}} {{#delegate-method}}{{/delegate-method}}{{operationId}}(
        {{#allParams}}{{>queryParams}}{{>pathParams}}{{>headerParams}}{{>bodyParams}}{{>formParams}}{{>cookieParams}}{{^-last}},
        {{/-last}}{{/allParams}}{{#reactive}}{{#hasParams}},
        {{/hasParams}}{{#swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}@Parameter(hidden = true){{/swagger2AnnotationLibrary}}{{#springFoxDocumentationProvider}}@ApiIgnore{{/springFoxDocumentationProvider}} final ServerWebExchange exchange{{/reactive}}{{#vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}}{{#hasParams}},
        {{/hasParams}}{{#springFoxDocumentationProvider}}@ApiIgnore {{/springFoxDocumentationProvider}}{{#springDocDocumentationProvider}}@ParameterObject {{/springDocDocumentationProvider}}final Pageable pageable{{/vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}}
    ){{#unhandledException}} throws Exception{{/unhandledException}}{{^jdk8-default-interface}};{{/jdk8-default-interface}}{{#jdk8-default-interface}} {
        {{#delegate-method}}
        return _{{operationId}}({{#allParams}}{{paramName}}{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/allParams}}{{#reactive}}{{#hasParams}}, {{/hasParams}}exchange{{/reactive}}{{#vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}}, pageable{{/vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}});
    }

    // Override this method
    {{#jdk8-default-interface}}default {{/jdk8-default-interface}} {{#responseWrapper}}{{.}}<{{/responseWrapper}}ResponseEntity<{{>returnTypes}}>>{{#responseWrapper}}{{/responseWrapper}} _{{operationId}}({{#allParams}}{{^isFile}}{{^isBodyParam}}{{>optionalDataType}}{{/isBodyParam}}{{#isBodyParam}}{{^reactive}}{{{dataType}}}{{/reactive}}{{#reactive}}{{^isArray}}{{{dataType}}}{{/isArray}}{{#isArray}}Flux<{{{baseType}}}>{{/isArray}}{{/reactive}}{{/isBodyParam}}{{/isFile}}{{#isFile}}{{#reactive}}Flux<Part>{{/reactive}}{{^reactive}}MultipartFile{{/reactive}}{{/isFile}} {{paramName}}{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/allParams}}{{#reactive}}{{#hasParams}}, {{/hasParams}}{{#springFoxDocumentationProvider}}@ApiIgnore{{/springFoxDocumentationProvider}} final ServerWebExchange exchange{{/reactive}}{{#vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}}, {{#springFoxDocumentationProvider}}@ApiIgnore{{/springFoxDocumentationProvider}} final Pageable pageable{{/vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}}){{#unhandledException}} throws Exception{{/unhandledException}} {
        {{/delegate-method}}
        {{^isDelegate}}
        {{>methodBody}}
        {{/isDelegate}}
        {{#isDelegate}}
        return getDelegate().{{operationId}}({{#allParams}}{{paramName}}{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/allParams}}{{#reactive}}{{#hasParams}}, {{/hasParams}}exchange{{/reactive}}{{#vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}}, pageable{{/vendorExtensions.x-spring-paginated}});
        {{/isDelegate}}
    }{{/jdk8-default-interface}}

{{/operation}}
}
{{/operations}}
```

**bodyParams.mustache**

```
{{#isBodyParam}}@Parameter(name = "{{{description}}}" {{#required}},required=true{{/required}} {{^isContainer}}{{#allowableValues}}, allowableValues="{{{allowableValues}}}"{{/allowableValues}}{{/isContainer}}{{#defaultValue}}, defaultValue="{{{defaultValue}}}"{{/defaultValue}})  {{#useBeanValidation}}@Valid{{/useBeanValidation}} @RequestBody {{{dataType}}} {{paramName}}{{/isBodyParam}}
```

then add the templateDirectory path to your  pom.xml swagger-codegen-maven-plugin configuration as follows:-

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
   <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <templateDirectory>src/main/resources/openapi-templates</templateDirectory>
           
           
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```